# printing the contents of the window calls before the window is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am printing my page with .print() method in javascript:

```html
var divToPrint = "<%=j render 'print_request' %>";
var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=600,height=600');
popupWin.document.write('<html><body>' + divToPrint + '</body></html>');
popupWin.print();

//popupWin.close();
```

So i am opening new blank page, put inside it my divToPrint and then send the page to the print.

The problem is that when I try to print for the first time, it seems that browser firstly tries to send page to print, as a result i get empty page, and only then writes divToPrint into the page.

When I try for the second time, it works, but only if .close() method is commented out. If I have .close(), it will not work even for the second try.

I guess my render 'print_request' not being able to load quickly and empty div is passed. Because sometimes it works after 4 or 5 attempts.

Comment: Make sure the page loads before you print. You can use `window.onload`

Comment: Also, try calling `close()` before you call `print()`